# Is there a way to get operational feedback from Linq2Sql database operations?

Tags: linq-to-sql, error-handling

Here's an attempt to clarify the question...

I previously used Linq2Sql with all data operations performed by stored procedures. In these stored procedures, I could return various (preset) error codes to signify different types of errors and also return any SQL error codes.  In my application framework, I had a nice way to lookup the error code, get a meaningful description of the error and then pass that useful feedback to the UI.

I've started a new project at work using Linq2Sql without any stored procedures (eg. just entity tables). The problem that I'm having is that I can't find any way to access the SQL error codes from the database after performing data operations, let alone my now non-existent custom error codes (no stored procedures, no custom error codes).

So my question is, 'Is there any way to retrieve this kind of error related feedback from the database after performing data operations?' I really need to know whether data operations have been carried out successfully or not.

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE >>>

After receiving the first answer, I feel that I should add a bit more to try and clarify things further. I had a situation where my Linq2Sql `DataContext` was not working (fixed now) and no data was being updated in the database, but no exceptions were being thrown. Therefore, I need to find a way to confirm that my data operations are succeeding... there must be some other form of confirmation better than 'the absence of exceptions'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with normal exception handling. If you get an error during the submitchanges, an exception will be raised

```
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    // Make some adjustments.
    // ...
    // Try again.
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: If I were to implement that for every call to SubmitChanges(), I would have so much extra code to write. Currently, my exceptions are handled on the next level up in one place that all database calls pass through, ie. one try and catch block. Anyway, I think you missed my point... I want to know if I can retrieve confirmation from SQL as one does when using stored procedures.

Comment: You should not have that many calls to Submitchanges. Only ONE per function (LUW). you would need this just as many times as you would handle the return code of yoyr SP. Plus: you do not need a confirmation, it you do not get an exception it has gone well.